# Roslyn Scripting API on .NET Core: why does compiler complain "error CS1501: no overload for WriteLine takes 2 arguments"?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, .net-core

I'm working on a project targeting `netcoreapp1.0` on OSX, and I'm setting up a script using Roslyn like this:

```
var scriptText = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);

var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default
    .WithReferences(
        typeof(System.Object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
    );

var script = CSharpScript.Create(scriptText, scriptOptions, typeof(Globals));

var scriptArgs = new string[args.Length-1];
Array.Copy(args, 1, scriptArgs, 0, args.Length-1);

script.RunAsync(new Globals
{ 
    Args = scriptArgs
})
.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Where `Globals` is:

```
public class Globals
{
    public string[] Args { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to run a script that looks like this:

```
using System;

Console.WriteLine("Args[0]: {0}", Args[0]);
```

The program terminates with this exception:

```
$ dotnet run test.csx
Project BitThicket.DotNet.ScriptTool (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Script error: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException: (7,9): error CS1501: No overload for method 'WriteLine' takes 2 arguments
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptBuilder.ThrowIfAnyCompilationErrors(DiagnosticBag diagnostics, DiagnosticFormatter formatter)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptBuilder.CreateExecutor[T](ScriptCompiler compiler, Compilation compilation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1.GetExecutor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1.RunAsync(Object globals, Func`2 catchException, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at BitThicket.DotNet.ScriptTool.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/ben/proj/bt/dotnet-scriptcs/src/BitThicket.DotNet.ScriptTool/Program.cs:line 63
```

Obviously `Console` does, in fact, have an overload that takes 2 methods.  I looked at the [CoreFx sources](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Console/src/System/Console.cs#L568) briefly to see if there were any odd type-forwarding or extension method tricks being used that might need additional care in the script setup, but I didn't see anything unusual there (maybe I missed something).

Why would the Roslyn `ScriptBuilder` then complain about this?

Comment: What happens when you use the new formatting style?  i.e. `Console.WriteLine($"Args[0]: {Args[0]}");`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @PhillipXT.  It does work with the string interpolation syntax, but it's kind of papering over the underlying issue - the script actually does more than just `Console.WriteLine`, but I'm running into a number of errors having to do with assembly references.  Hopefully figuring out the real issue here will help light the way for the other problems, too.

Comment: Just wanted to check and make sure Args[0] wasn't the problem somehow.  Not sure what else could be wrong with the WriteLine...

Comment: using System reference should be added to scriptoptions with reference call

Comment: use of string.format might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .NET Core, the `Console` class is in the `System.Console` assembly, so you'll need to add it to the script's references:

```
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default
    .WithReferences(
        typeof(System.Object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
        typeof(System.Console).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
    );
```

If you check the assembly location of `Object`, you'll see it's `System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll`. Using ILSpy, we can see this assembly only contains a basic `Console` implementation, with the methods `Write(string s)`, `WriteLine(string s)` and `WriteLine()`. Whereas the `System.Console` assembly contains the full implementation.

Comment: I'm not at my computer to try it at the moment, but if this is the case, then why wouldn't the compiler fail on finding the `Console` type altogether in my example?